# User Login(pin) -> error(pin):"Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

When I click on the sign in button I should see my data i.e. email and password, but I get this error. Do you know how I can fix it?
I thought maybe at useEffect is the problem where I used navigate

this is LoginScreen.js code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, FormLabel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { login } from '../actions/userActions'
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer'

function LoginScreen( ) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation()

    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const { error, loading, userInfo } = userLogin

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
            navigate('/redirect')
        }

    }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect])


    const submitHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(login(email, password))
    }



  return (
    <FormContainer>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
        {loading && <Loader />}

        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

            <Form.Group controlId='email'>
                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type='email'
                    placeholder='Enter Email'
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                >
                </Form.Control>

            </Form.Group>


            <Form.Group controlId='password'>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Enter Password'
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                >
                </Form.Control>

            </Form.Group>

            <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
                Sign In
            </Button>

        </Form>
        <Row className='py-3'>
            <Col>
                New Customer? <Link
                to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}`:'/register'}>
                Register    
                </Link>
            </Col>
        </Row>
     
    </FormContainer>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

I have attached a screenshot with the error here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DxHL.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75551743/uncaught-typeerror-0-actions-useractions-js-webpack-imported-module-5-log **I have a similar problem**

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you do some changing in userAction and LoginScreen.

userAction:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
    USER_LOGOUT,
} from '../constants/userConstants'

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
        })

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `api/users/login`,
            { 'username': email, 'password': password },
            config
        )

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

        localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

This is LoginScreen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer'
import { login } from '../actions/userActions'

function LoginScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const history = useHistory()
  const location = useLocation

  const dispatch = useDispatch()


  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
  const { error, loading, userInfo } = userLogin

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push(redirect)
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, redirect])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loader />}
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

        <Form.Group controlId='email'>
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='email'
            placeholder='Enter Email'
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          >
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>


        <Form.Group controlId='password'>
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='password'
            placeholder='Enter Password'
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          >
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </Form>

      <Row className='py-3'>
        <Col>
          New Customer? <Link
            to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : '/register'}>
            Register
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>

    </FormContainer>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].